# Azure Blob Storage role based access control

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, rbac

Is there any role based access control for Azure Blob Storage? I'm aware of SAS tokens and ACL, which are great, but ACL allows only for 5 entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any role based access control for Azure Blob Storage?

Not as of today. You have to use Shared Access Signature for access control. The limit of 5 access policies is per container. One possibility would be to have multiple containers.

Comment: So what's the design to serve your content from Blob Storage to various users with various rights (which sometimes are revoked)? Generate short expiration date tokens?

Comment: `Generate short expiration date tokens`: This is definitely one of the ways to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: A container can have up to 5 stored access policies, if you need to create more than 5 access rules to control users’ accessing the blobs, as Gaurav Mantri said, you could try to create multiple containers. Besides, as we know, with a valid SAS, anyone who gets the URI can use it. If you’d like to implement role-based access control for your blob storage, you could write code in your application to detect user’s role and make logical judgement to determine whether current user has permission to access blob resources.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches is to have middleware which does RBAC or ACL stuff then on succession, generate short expiration SAS token from Azure and next is to redirect(via HTTP header) user to the SAS URI.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1